# How to scale UIButton without scaling image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Can anyone help me scale a UIButton without scaling UIButton's imageView?

This code scale button and button's imageView. I want the button to be scaled without scaling the imageView.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 126/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)
button.layer.cornerRadius = $0.bounds.size.width / 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Image in button Image. will not scale but you can set button as you want. See in the image my button have 100*100 image and button have more size than image.

[image]

Comment: I want to scale button without scaling button's image

Comment: ok then create button reference 
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,25,25,25)

Comment: Thanks.  button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,25,25,25)  before button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3) works

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to create a UIImageView as a subview inside the button that you can control however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, And set content insets from storyboard.

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 126/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

[image]

Comment: If content inset is 12 from each direction and the button gets bigger the image will still get bigger..

Comment: Set content insets as your requirement, and then set contentMode .scaleAspectFit